# Is there any MSBuild property that shows we are in publish?

Tags: msbuild

I want to conditionally undefine `DEBUG` if it's a publish build.

is there a property I can check to see if we're currently publishing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this issue-comment](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/26324#issuecomment-1169236993) in the `dotnet/sdk` repository. Microsoft seemingly introduced the MSBuild-variable `_IsPublishing` which can be used to check if we're in a publish-build.
This variable will contain `yes` if we are indeed doing `dotnet publish` and is empty if we are not.

Note however, that this variable will not be set, when using `dotnet build /t:Publish` or `msbuild /t:Publish`.

Answer (score 4):

You can wire in your own target to set a property that you can then key behavior off of, or do whatever you want.  The project modification below shows how to wire into the existing Publish target dependencies with your own before and after target.  The before target sets a property.  Then, in the existing part of your project where DEBUG is defined within the $(DefineConstants) property, you conditionally decide on whether or not to add DEBUG into the constant list, based on the property you set when the build is being performed because of a Publish.

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <PublishDependsOn>MyBeforePublish;$(PublishDependsOn);MyAfterPublish</PublishDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="MyBeforePublish">
   <PropertyGroup>
      <DetectPublishBuild>true</DetectPublishBuild>
   </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
<Target Name="MyAfterPublish">
   <PropertyGroup>
      <DetectPublishBuild>false</DetectPublishBuild>
   </PropertyGroup>
</Target>

...

<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
   <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
   <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
   <DebugType>full</DebugType>
   <Optimize>false</Optimize>
   <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
   <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
   <DefineConstants
      Condition="'$(DetectPublishBuild)' != 'true'"
      >DEBUG;$(DefineConstants)</DefineConstants>
   <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
   <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Is the `PublishDependsOn` property defined for winforms, website, and webapplication projects?

Answer (score 4):

Tested in VS2019 16.10.1.

```xml
<Target Name="XXX" Condition="'$(PublishProtocol)'!=''">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<Copy SourceFiles="Web.Base.config" DestinationFiles="Web.config" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="True" Condition="!('$(PublishProfileName)' == '' And '$(WebPublishProfileFile)' == '')" />
```

This will perform the "Copy" only when the build is using the PublishProfile flag.

http://sedodream.com/2013/01/06/commandlinewebprojectpublishing.aspx

Answer (score -3):

```
<Choose>
      <When Condition="'$(BuildType)' == 'publish'">
         <PropertyGroup>
           <DefineConstants>Release</DefineConstants>
         </PropertyGroup>
      </When>      
</Choose>
```

You may need other values in there besides release. But, this should work.

What we do at our place though is to actually have a publish, debug, and release. We created publish by having it copy from release so it has all the settings in it.

Comment: ``$(BuildType)`` seems to be user-defined and thus not directly usable.

Comment: BuildType not found.